# Why doesn't VALIDATE CONSTRAINT find this foreign key violation?

Tags: postgresql

I don't think I understand what VALIDATE CONSTRAINT is supposed to do.  I am converting a database for use in the upcoming major upgrade of my company's flagship software product.  Past developers were lazy, and didn't bother specifying foreign keys where they should have.  For the new version of our product, appropriate foreign keys will be specified and enforced.

So, I want to import data into my new database and then make sure there are no foreign key violations.  After wrestling with when transactions begin and end and dealing with circular keys and getting nowhere at amazing speed, I decided merely disable all triggers on all tables (which disables foreign key constraint checking in PostgreSQL, since they use triggers under the hood), import my data, re-enable the triggers, and then issue a VALIDATE CONSTRAINT command.  However, in my little test script, the validation fails to find any constraint violations.  Why not?

Here's the test script.  I am creating a table named gas_types_minimum with a column named gas_type.  I am not creating any records in that table.  Then, I create a table named base_types_minimum with a column named base_type and a column named gas_type.  I disable its triggers so I can insert a base_type record even though there is no gas_type record.  Then, I insert a Hydrogen base type with a gas type of 'H2'.  Then, I turn triggers back on and validate the constraint.  I get no error.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS base_types_minimum;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gas_types_minimum;
CREATE TABLE public.gas_types_minimum
(
    gas_type character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT gas_type_minimum_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gas_type)
);

CREATE TABLE public.base_types_minimum
(
    base_type character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    gas_type character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT base_type_minimum_pkey PRIMARY KEY (base_type),
    CONSTRAINT base_type_minimum_gas_type_minimum_fk FOREIGN KEY (gas_type)
        REFERENCES public.gas_types_minimum (gas_type) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

alter table base_types_minimum disable trigger all;
insert into base_types_minimum values ('Hydrogen', 'H2');
alter table base_types_minimum enable trigger all;

alter table base_types_minimum validate constraint base_type_minimum_gas_type_minimum_fk;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the foreign key constraint is already marked as valid, so it is not checked.

`VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` is only useful for constraints that were *defined* as `NOT VALID`, which your constraint was not. There is no supported way to invalidate a constraint later on, because it is not considered useful.

By disabling the triggers you effectively broke integrity, and there is no way to recover. That is why you can only disable a trigger that implements a foreign key if you are a superuser (these are expected to know what they are doing).

The best thing for you to do is to drop the broken foreign key constraint.

There is one – unsupported! – way how you can mark the constraint invalid:

```
UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_constraint
SET convalidated = FALSE
WHERE conname = 'base_type_minimum_gas_type_minimum_fk';
```

You can only do that as superuser, and I don't recommend it. Just drop that foreign key constraint.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Since this conversion is very rare and I do have superuser access, I wouldn't mind doing it, but I think this would just be too fancy.  I tend to waste far too much time on fancy solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was struggling to find out the truth about this! Here is a cookie: 